# Is there a reverse or opposite of submodules?

Tags: node.js, git, express, workflow, git-submodules

I am currently working on a large project with multiple teams. We have a a nodejs server running express to handle requests and have built out all of the routes.

Right now, all of the routes point to stubs. What I would like to do is be able to break out each stub as a submodule that each team can work on independently. Normally we would create separate projects for each section and build them independently, only bringing them together for the final product but this usually takes a lot of work to test each project separately with the server and then again with them all together.

Is there any way that we can do the reverse of submodules? For example, We have project A (the core Express server), which project B and project C can checkout under separately, resulting in something like:

Projects: A, A+B, A+C

`The use case would be, we have one team working on the server (http handling).
Another team (B) can pull from Project A's master branch to work on their stub - User handling. 
Yet another team (C) can pull from Project A's master branch to work on their stub - Order handling.`

Can we have a shared root project that we can pull updates from while allowing us to work on only our piece of the server? Or are projects inside projects the only way?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a private npm registry?

Comment: That could be a possibility. How would I organize the projects? Would I publish the superproject (A) and require it in the others, or would I publish the others and require them in A?

Answer (score 0):

If it's technically possible to checkout the core server and the handler's code *side-by-side* and then somehow make them see each other—for instance, via symlinking,—then use submodule—just the other way around: a handler project would have the core server as its submodule.

Barring that, you might consider so-called "subtree merging" which
is basically a way to merge a remote repository under a prefix (a subdirectory) of your repository.

The latter can be done either
[by hand](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html)
or with [`git subtree`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) helper
which is integrated into Git proper since some time, and before that was available as its "contrib" script (FWIW, on Debian and its derivatives it was packaged in a way to be directly available as well).